# Issue parsing a number on webpage via BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I would like to parse a number from [this website dashboard](https://www.semrush.com/info/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yelp.com%2Fbiz%2Fplayground-2-0-santa-ana-3?db=us). The number is located beneath "Organic Search"

Using a simple cmd-F on the soup, I eventually realized that my soup doesn't contain this number at all. It would be great to hear suggestions on why this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page is rendered by JavaScrip, the response will be:

[image]

the real data is in this url:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://us.backend.semrush.com/?key=adb79c4ec6282f461fb0e2e67aa50949&action=report&type=url_organic&currency=usd&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yelp.com%2Fbiz%2Fplayground-2-0-santa-ana-3&_=1486008342774')
data = r.json()
data['organic']['traffic']
```

Comment: you can call it without `jsoncallback=jQuery21407727922755626626_1486008342773` and you get pure JSON and then you can use `json` module.

Comment: @furas WoW, Thanks.

Comment: `jsoncallback` is very popular method to send data and automatically execute function assigned to `jsoncallback` - it is called `JSONP` - see [What is JSONP all about?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me understand the problem more clearly, however what is the proper way to parse this particular page:

'https://us.backend.semrush.com/?key=adb79c4ec6282f461fb0e2e67aa50949&action=report&type=url_organic&currency=usd&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yelp.com%2Fbiz%2Fplayground-2-0-santa-ana-3&_=1486008342774'

I am considering using PhantomJS because you mentioned js, and there seems to be some way to do it using BeautifulSoup 4 as well. I am still a beginner with DOM and web parsing in general, thanks